# How to graph $|z+1| + |z-7| = 10$? Please help me.

Tags: complex-numbers

The solution indicated that it is a oval , center $(3,0)$
and $a = 10/2 $.

Comment: Just a hint: Take $z=x+iy$

Comment: Thanks sir,but i stuck with                        ((x+1)^2 + y^2))^1/2 + ((x-7)^2 + y^2))^1/2 = 10

Comment: How to continue

Comment: Search the definition of an ellipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to say that the sum of the radii $\underbrace{|z+1|}_{r_1}+\underbrace{|z-7|}_{r_2}=\underbrace{10}_{2a},$
according to the definition on Wolfram Mathworld http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipse.html

Comment: Oh thanks you very much.

Comment: If you like my answer, feel free to upvote / click the check mark by my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can see it as an ellipse with focuses $(-1,0)$ and $(7,0)$ and $a=10/2$.

Comment: Excuse me, can you tell why focuses (1,0) and (7,0)? Is it definition?

Comment: @PhoopanPantamui: What is an ellipse? This is a nice hint.

Comment: Oh! i got it.Thanks you very much.